# Resuming Activities in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, menu

I have an Android app that basically has 3 activities: game menu, showcase of data, and the game itself.

When you complete the game the app is supposed to send you to the game menu. From what I understand this Activity is already running in the background, in order to go back I use:

```
 private Runnable aDesbloqueo = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(moduloCuerpoGame.this, GameMenu.class));
        }
 };
```

Now this creates a new "menu" activity, so when I press the back button it goes back to my "last" activity, then to the middle one, and then to the menu.

The question is, what is the best way to go back to the menu from the last Activity without creating any new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding `android:launchMode=“singleInstance”` to that Activity in your manifest? Single instance means that Android won't create a new instance of your Activity every time you create a new Intent. Rather, it destroys the previous instance of that Activity in your "Activity stack."

Try checking out the [Activity instance documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for a more detailed explaination.